# WordPress: Hide all the pages and posts expect for some pages

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a multisite installation and I'm using one site for my landing pages. I want to hide all the pages on that site expect the landing pages that you need to have the URL to access.

I searched for a plugin that could do that but didn't find one. Is there anything that we can do with .htaccess? I tried looking into this but just looking at .htaccess gives me a headache and I don't want to break something for the other sites as this is MS installation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect from sites u don't want to be visible into other sites. In order to do this u can use this plugin:

https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

or if u know some php u can use hook and redirect.
Write and adjust in functions.php code below:

```
function wolfie_redirect_sample() {

if(is_front_page()) { //in this place u can use any other conditional
     exit( wp_redirect( site_url( '/this_is_ur_landing' ) ) );
}

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wolfie_redirect_sample' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the plugin worked fine. I was worried that it won't redirect the index page, but it worked fine. As for the PHP code, I was wondering what is 'template_redirect'? Just curious :) Thanks again

Comment: oh.. if u're beginner in wordpress I highly recommand official wordpress codex. All u need is patiance and keep going. Basicly hooks are a 'places in wordpress' which u can run a code. And this exact hook is a place where u can run redirectaions via php files. Loops and hooks is first thing to learn in wp. Cheers!